# What if the rewards are revealed in a bandit problem

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit

Take a n-armed bandit setup. When agent pulls an arm, the environment reveals rewards of all arms at that time step. 
My question is will existing algorithms work well in this setting ? Can we take advantage of all the information revealed to us ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think many algorithms take the advantage of all the information revealed by all the other arms at a time stamp.

#### Let's take RL (Reinforcement Learning) for e.g

There is a trade off of exploration and exploitation in RL. We apply e-greedy policy in which our agent chooses the action that corresponds to the largest expected value with e probability. In this we can easily see our agent is exploiting information given by different arms to continue to learn more about them.